# Is there anything in ~/.cache that is not really cache?

Tags: cache, tmpfs

My machine has lots of memory, so I moved `~/.cache/google-chrome` into `/tmp`, which is a tmpfs RAM disk.
This makes the browser run faster and reduces SSD usage.
When I reboot, it all goes away, but it gets recreated again.
All is fine.

In theory, I could move all of `~/.cache` there too.

But in practice, how likely is it that some packages (ab)use `~/.cache` for something other than temporary reproducible data?

#### Update (2 days later):

I decided to try it out and did this:

```
$ mv ~/.cache ~/.cache.old
$ ln  -s  /tmp/home/ray/.cache  ~/.
```

and then added this to my `~/.profile`:

```
mkdir  -p  /tmp/home/ray/.cache
```

and so far everything is working okay across reboots.  Removing .cache.old will free up about 2G of mostly ancient files.

If I ever *do* run into any packages that misuse .cache, I can teach `.profile` to add a symlink back to a real directory for that specific case.

#### Update (3 years later):

I've been running this for over 3 years now with no obvious problems.

Comment: It's unfortunate, but I've already run into a couple of apps that do store preferences in ~/.cache, the most glaring being Evolution. You're probably going to have to test each app individually to see what breaks.